# How to apply the Merge function to the Range object which is selected from the user using InputBox?

Tags: excel, vba, macos, excel-formula

I tried to apply the merge function to the range object which is return from the InputBox by selecting the ranges from the user .But error is occruing

> "Run-Time Error "1004" : Method "Range" of Object '_Global" failed.`

```
Sub SelectRangeandMerge()
   Dim UserRange As Range
   Set UserRange = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please Select Range ", _
                Title:="Range Select ", Type:=8)
   Range("UserRange").Merge
End Sub
```

Comment: `UserRange` is not a string.... try `UserRange.Merge` instead or `UserRange = InputBox()` and define it as a string, and then `Range(UserRange).Merge`

Comment: @braX I think your comment better go as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UserRange` is not a literal `String`.... try `UserRange.Merge` instead or better yet, `UserRange = InputBox()` and define it as a string instead (since `InputBox` returns a `String` not an `Object`), and then `Range(UserRange).Merge` using it as a variable.